# Deserialize List<Interface> with jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I want to deserialize json to class Foo:

```
class Foo {
   List<IBar> bars;
}

interface IBar {
   ...
}

class Bar implements IBar {
   ...
}
```

IBar has two implementations, but when deserializing I always want to use the first implementation. (This should ideally make the problem easier, because there is no runtime type checking required)

I am sure I can write custom deserializers, but felt there must be something easier.

I found this annotation, which works perfectly when there is no list.

```
@JsonDeserialize(as=Bar.class)
IBar bar;

List<IBar> bars; // Don't know how to use the annotation here.
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
@JsonDeserialize(contentAs=Bar.class)
List<IBar> bars;
```

Comment: What is the solution if I have multiple implementations of IBar? I have an object that has list of IBar object. It can be dynamically Bar1.class or Bar2.class. Any way I can handle this?

Comment: @Maz did you manage to solve your problem with multiple implementations

Comment: Yes. I used Jackson Polymorphism solution and it worked.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Running into JsonMappingExceptoion
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to narrow value type of [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class com.test...IBar]] with concrete-type annotation (value com.test...Bar), from '': Class com.test..Bar not subtype of [simple type, class com.test...IBar]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a `TypeReference` ?

For instance...

Json file `test.json` in `/your/path/`:

```
[{"s":"blah"},{"s":"baz"}]
```

Main class in package `test`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            List<IBar> actuallyFoos = mapper.readValue(
                    new File("/your/path/test.json"), new TypeReference<List<Foo>>() {
                    });
            for (IBar ibar : actuallyFoos) {
                System.out.println(ibar.getClass());
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static interface IBar {
        public String getS();

        public void setS(String s);
    }

    static class Foo implements IBar {
        protected String s;

        public String getS() {
            return s;
        }

        public void setS(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }
    }

    static class Bar implements IBar {
        protected String s;

        public String getS() {
            return s;
        }

        public void setS(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }
    }
}
```

Output of the `main` method:

```
class test.Main$Foo
class test.Main$Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the annotation on the `IBar` interface declaration rather than the field, ie:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as=Bar.class)
interface IBar {
   ...
}
```